# Problema de conversion de fecha utilizando VBA de excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hola estoy haciendo una macros que me cambia toda una columna que esta con fecha de este tipo dd.mm.yyyy a dd-mm-yyy, y utilicé el siguiente comando:

```
Range("E:E).Select
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
```

Sin embargo al transcribirlo me invierte el dia con el mes, tambien probé con el codigo :

```
Range("E:E).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

y sigo ocurriendo lo mismo. La solución de cambiarlo celda por celda si bien sirve, en este caso no me sirve mucho porque son muchos datos y así se demora mucho. Así que si alguien tiene una manera de hacerlo remplazando todos los valores como lo hago arriba sería de mucha ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Aquí las causas pueden ser varias. ¿Es posible ver el archivo? No se necesita el resto de datos, solo la columna que te da problemas, y también pon al lado cómo debería quedar. Pero ver el archivo ayudaría.

Comment: El cambio en el orden posiblemente sea algún modo por defecto de interpretar el valor modificado como fecha, dándole una máscara por defecto desde el formato de celda (y por defecto aquí seguro será en formato gringo, con el mes primero)

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente la línea

```
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="-",...
```

realiza la operación de cambio mal. Solo funciona si el día de la fecha origen es superior a 12. En ese caso el código realiza el ***Replace*** perfectamente.

Para evitar eso la solución es formatear las celdas en modo texto (ya lo habías hecho), seleccionar solo el rango limitado y hacer un ***For Each***.

Este código funciona perfectamente.

```
'VBA
Private Sub f_MiFuncion()

    'Obligatorio si no queremos que recorra la columna entera
    Range("E1", "E" & Range("E1").End(xlDown).Row).Select

    'Obligatorio para que Excel no haga swap ddmm->mmdd
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    'Este método no genera errores de swap
    For Each obj_cell In Selection.Cells
        With obj_cell
            If IsNull(obj_cell) Then Exit Sub
            obj_cell.Value = Replace(.Text, ".", "-")
        End With
    Next
   'Volvemos a formatear como Fecha
    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy;@"
End
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó lo mismo, del día 1 al 12 la macro  me importaba las fechas con formato fecha internacional y del 13 en adelante como fecha tradicional. Lo solucioné Declarando la variable como Date.

En la macro que utilices, antes de pasar la variable a la celda final debes declarar esa variable como Date,
Si tu variable la llamas fecha:

```
    Dim fecha as Date
    fecha = Range(x,y)
```

De esta manera no tendrías que cambiar el formato de la celda.

Answer (score 0):

He seguido investigando y he encontrado otro método que hace el cambio de forma inmediata aunque lo deja en el formato dd/mm/aaaa. Si quieres cambiar **'/'** por **'-'** has de utilizar el método  ***For Each*** con un ***Replace*** mencionado en mi anterior respuesta.

Este otro método utiliza ***Range.TextToColumns*** junto con ***FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)***

**Es increíble pero se queda solo en una línea. Además la celda no solo sigue formateada en fecha sino que admite cualquier carácter como separador de fechas.**

```
Range("E:E").TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
'1.2.2019 -> 01/02/2019
```

Ejemplo de caracteres admitidos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Llevaba horas atascado con este problema y por error encontré la solución (de antemano decir que estoy aprendiendo a programar).

En vez de intentar forzar el formato para que cambie a `DD/MM/YYYY` que es lo que intentaba:

```
ActiveCell.Value = Format(Combo_fecha.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

Forcé el formato para que lo pusiera en inglés, ya que a partir del día 12 me lo cambiaba y lo que pretendía es que lo pusiera en inglés siempre y luego ya con código cambiaría el orden.

```
ActiveCell.Value = Format(Combo_fecha.Value, "MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Y la celda que recibía el valor estaba configurada en formato español.

Mi sorpresa fue que al hacer esto el excel reconoce que es inglés pero como está con formato español automáticamente lo pone correctamente.

Más fácil imposible y me sorprende no haber encontrado esta solución en ningún lado, pero como dije antes yo la encontré por error.